# Set Print Area for Excel Files

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have an Excel file all of which has columns until col `N`. My question is I want to know how to set the print area using VBScript to cover each row until column `N` until a blank row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on which column you want to use to check for the first blank row. Here's an example that checks for the last row with data in column A:

```
Const xlUp = -4162
Const xlCellTypeBlanks = 4

' Get the last row...
Dim intLastRow
intLastRow = objWSheet.Cells(objWSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Delete any rows with a blank column A...
objWSheet.Range("A1:A" & intLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

' Get the new last row...
intLastRow = objWSheet.Cells(objWSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Set the print area...
objWSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$N$" & intLastRow
```

Comment: If I wanted to write it in as a VBScript also would this syntax would work as well?

Comment: Well, in VBScript, you need to qualify your objects since you're not in the VBA environment. `Cells` and `PageSetup` aren't going to be available. You'd have to use `objExcel.ActiveSheet.Cells`, or whatever your Excel object reference is called.

Comment: Ah I see, if I may ask what would be the syntax for it in a VBScript?

Comment: Why did you tag it as [vba] if you wanted [vbscript]?

Comment: I originally wanted VBA, but I am asked for a vbscript, my apologies.

Comment: What's the name of your Excel object? And should I use the `ActiveSheet` in my example or do you have a preference?

Comment: I called my Excel object objwb and my ActiveSheet objWSheet, but in the end I don't have a preference as long I know which is which. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I've updated it to show the code in VBScript with a sheet variable called `objWSheet`.

Comment: I get a run-time error on this line, intLastRow = objWSheet.Cells(objWSheet.Rows.Count, objWSheet.Columns("A").Column).End(xlUp).Row, trying to figure out why.

Comment: Probably just need to define `xlUp`. I've edited the answer to include that constant.

Comment: I just tried that, it now compiles and runs although the print area still includes many blank rows underneath the last row containing data in the print area.

Comment: You probably have some rows that once had data in them. Try the updated code. It will remove any blank rows before setting the print area.

Comment: Ah I figured out my mistake, the problem was that what is seen to be an empty cell was not an empty cell rather it contained a formula. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless your sheet has more data rows after that blank row you could simply use the [`UsedRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) property:

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True

Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\path\to\your.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ws.UsedRange.Address
```